# grails - spring security oauth2 vs rest

Tags: spring-security, spring-security-oauth2, spring-security-rest

I have site in grails, and now I need to add API support. Third party application will be using it to access resources. I thought of using Spring Security OAuth2 plugin ([Plugin link](https://grails.org/plugin/spring-security-oauth2-provider)) for that, but I would like, for now, to skip asking user to authorise application (Is that possible?).
Also, I found Spring Security REST ([Plugin link](https://grails.org/plugin/spring-security-rest)).

I have in plan creating also my own mobile application, so I am not sure what is the better solution. Or is it better to use OAuth2 for third party applications and then REST plugin for my own app? What are benefits of one plugin compared to the other?